# Why is TeX functionality for mathematical typesetting not found on standard word processors, like MS Word?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, msword

It doesn't seem hard to me to put the symbols in the product, and allow users to draw mathematical formulas. Is the user pool too small to attract the interest of major software companies?